# Как конвертировать String в Char что бы вывести из функции?

Tags: java, строки, char

```java
public class TwoDimensionalArray {

    public static final char SYMBOL = 'X';
    public static String symbol2 = String.valueOf(SYMBOL);

    public static char[][] getTwoDimensionalArray(int size) {

        String[][] cross = new String[size][size];


        for (int i = 0; i < cross.length; i++) {
            for (int j = 0; j < cross[i].length; j++) {
                cross[i][j] = (j == i || j == cross.length - 1 - i) ? symbol2 : " ";
                System.out.print(cross[i][j]);
            }
            System.out.println();
        }
       

> return new char[][];

    }
}
```

закончились варианты как вывести cross из функции

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Там ничего не надо конвертировать, достаточно присваивать элементам двумерного массива `char[][]` значение `SYMBOL`.

Также можно обойтись и без вложенного цикла, заполняя каждую строку при помощи `Arrays.fill`, и устанавливая сразу `X` на обеих диагоналях:

```java
private static final char SYMBOL = 'X';

public static char[][] getTwoDimensionalArray(int size) {

    char[][] cross = new char[size][size];

    for (int i = 0; i < cross.length; i++) {
        Arrays.fill(cross[i], ' ');
        cross[i][i] = cross[i][size - 1 - i] = SYMBOL;
        System.out.println(new String(cross[i]));
    }
    return cross;
}
```